# WP_Query with an array of IDs order by array

Tags: wordpress, sorting

I have an array of IDs and I want to get that posts by WP_Quey()

```
$myarray = $ids;
$args = array( 'post__in' => $myarray);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Its, Sort result by date But I want to sort it by $myarray items and first result would be first ID in $myarray

Comment: Ur question is not very clear. But if you want to sort posts by ID in your array then, you can use orderby=>'ID'. Here is the args array. $args = array( 'post__in' => $myarray, 'orderby'=>ID, 'order'=>'ASC');

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Wordpress 3.5 and up you can use `'orderby'=>'post__in'` then you must write this:

```
$myarray = $ids;    
$args = array('post__in'=> $myarray, 'orderby'=>'post__in');
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: But what if you want to include all ids, not just post__in?

Answer (score 0):

I know, that my answer is too late, but i have to answer correctly.

As i tried `'orderby'=>'post__in'`:

for example i have dynamically updated cookies, and i must to load products in recently viewed products block in order, that first product in this block must be last viewed.

OK.

I had ids **1720, 19626, 19173, 19188**.

```
$args = array('post__in'=> $myarray, 'orderby'=>'post__in');
```

This string in output returned my products in order:

**19626, 19188, 19173, 1720** and its not my order. This cause simply order parameter  **DESC** by default `WP_Query`. And we have only one another chance - `ASC` it...very sad answer by M H.

My answer is simply clever:

we DO NOT NEED to **'orderby'=>'post__in'**

we have to get:

```
$myarray = $ids;    
$args = array('post__in'=> $myarray);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

After it we do:

```
foreach($myarray as $myarray_id){
 while ( $the_query->have_posts()) {
   $the_query->the_post();
   if($post->ID == $myarray_id){
     //DO SOMETHING
   }
 }
}
```

That's it!

Comment: This answer seems to suggest that the earlier answer by M H, simply using 'orderby'=>'post__in' doesn't work. However, for me that works fine, and I find it an easier solution to be honest. Maybe I'm missing something or maybe the behavior changed in WordPress in the meantime but I can confirm that 'orderby'=>'post__in' works fine to sort by the selected ids in the order that I list them in the array, nothing further seems needed.

Answer (score -3):

Properly transmitting the order:

```
$id_array = array(5,2,3,7);

foreach($id_array as $id_array_v)
{
   $query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => array($id_array_v)));

   while($query -> have_posts())
   {
      $query -> the_post();
      the_title();
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code does? Please consider revising to avoid deletion. (review team)

Comment: properly transmitting the order